# Configurando o Visual Studio para usar o GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk, visual-studio-2017

Eu já andei pesquisando e o único lugar onde eu achei algo semelhante foi no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010) em inglês, onde é descrito a configuração para uso do GTK+ no Visual Studio 2010. Pela pouca experiência que tenho, pensei que poderia configurar para uso no VS 2017 tranquilamente.

No entanto, veio os erros de DLL's não encontradas. A variável de ambiente está devidamente configurada(GTK+\bin), assim como eu fiz todos os procedimentos informados.

A aplicação chega a ser compilada, no entanto, ao iniciar-se, o sistema não encontra as dll´s do runtime do GTK+. Mas, a não ser que eu não saiba estar configurando a variável de ambiente que aponta para as dll's do runtime do GTK+ corretamente, simplesmente não sei o que se passa.

Existe algum passo diferente a ser realizado?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A aplicação chega a ser compilada, no entanto, ao iniciar-se, o sistema não encontra as dll´s do runtime do GTK+. Mas, a não ser que eu não saiba estar configurando a variável de ambiente que aponta para as dll's do runtime do GTK+ corretamente, simplesmente não sei o que se passa.

Comment: Paulo, o ideal seria adicionar este comentário a pergunta. Vou fazer isso aqui. Se você tiver um print desse erro de DLL nao encontrada sera mais facil para entender tbm.

Comment: É um erro de dll não encontrada. Trata-se de uma dll do runtime do gtk+.

Comment: Eu devo adicionar à variável "Path" o caminho para as bibliotecas do gtk+, que estão em C:\GTK+\bin, correto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As instruções em [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010) estão corretas e, como esperado, funcionam perfeitamente para VS 2017. 
Eu, certamente devo ter me equivocado na configuração da variável de ambiente system Path